# Как Extended WPF Toolkit добавить в ToolBox

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

Скачал через NuGet `Extended WPF Toolkit`.

Добавил в *.xaml строку `xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"`.

Добавил в *.cs строку `using Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;`.

В теории уже могу создавать и использовать компоненты в коде (не проверял).
Мне бы их в `ToolBox` поместить)

Google мне почему то не помог...

Comment: В качестве несложного обходного пути, попробуйте редактировать XAML вручную. Не исключено, что так вам покажется эффективнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто на `ToolBox` перетащите `Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.dll`

или `ToolBox->Сhoose Items...->WPF Components->Browse...->OK`

Для удобства луче предварительно создать вкладку с названием `Extended WPF Toolkit` и туда добавить.

Comment: Ошибка:
There are no components in "Путь к dll" that can be placed on the toolbox.

Comment: @АлександрЛи обноволи ответ, скорее всего нужно было выбрать вкладку `WPF Components`